# How do I know in an accepted a outlook meeting request that I am required or optional

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, meeting-request

I was sent an outlook meeting invite with other people which I accepted and now it shows in my outlook. The meeting request was sent a while ago and the original meeting request is deleted and doesn't exists even in my deleted mails folder.

Now I want to know if I was in the list of required people or optional ?

I am using outlook 2013.

Comment: Ask the meeting organiser?

Comment: You can try recover deleted items but yes, why don't you ask the organiser?

Answer (score 9):

Here are two options:

1. Open the meeting in the calendar view and click on the scheduling assistant button - this lists all invitees with their required/optional status
2. Add some custom formatting to show optional meetings visually.

   - Right click on the calendar
   - Select "View Settings"
   - Select "Conditional formatting"
   - Add a new rule, give it a name and a colour of choice
   - Select "Condition" and then "Advanced"
   - Click "Field", select "All appointment fields" and then "Optional attendees"
   - Set the condition to "includes" and the value to your name.
   - Optional appointments should then show up in a different colour.